# SpringFramework 3.x @Scheduled background task stopped with unknown reason

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a application written in SpringMVC 3.2.6. There are multiple background tasks are annotated with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = ...)`. They running several weeks all good. Recently I found all background tasks are not running anymore. There is no Exception reported in the log file.

Does anyone has similar experience? Any clue on what happened? and how to trace the root cause?

Thanks,
Green

Comment: Was there a deployment between the time it was working and when it stopped?  If someone changed the code between deployments, I would start by looking at those changes.

Comment: I had a deadlock in scheduled task that would block only in very rare circumstances. After several weeks, pool assigned to scheduled tasks was exhausted and new tasks would not run anymore. I suggest taking a thread dump and see if threads are blocked somewhere.